# What does 1- means in Running Time of Slurm Job

Tags: slurm

I'm using slurm and I have several jobs and I get:

`JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
             35633    normal name  user  R 1-06:50:00      1 pbil-X1
             45677    normal name  user  R 1-03:00:00      1 pbil-X2`

What does the `-1` in `1-06:50:00` means? 
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1-06:50:00` means **1 day** 6 jours and 50 minutes. From the [sacct manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html):

```
Elapsed
  The jobs elapsed time.
  The format of this fields output is as follows:
    [DD-[HH:]]MM:SS
  as defined by the following:
  DD
    days
  hh
    hours
  mm
    minutes
  ss
    seconds
```